# How can I get an endorsement back from a specific peer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

Is there a way to get endorsements back from specific peer(s) after submitting a transaction in Hyperledger fabric, using `contract.submitTransaction()` or `channel.sendTransaction()`?
So far the endorsements always seem to come back from the same peer and not other peers in the organization.  Please see my environment details below.
Also if I target specific peers using the node sdk `sendTransactionProposal(request)'s` ChaincodeInvokeRequest preferred or ignore list, that doesn't seem to make any difference.
Is there any specific documentation or an alternative resource available that addresses this issue?

ChaincodeInvokeRequest{
  targets: allPeers or peer2, // or a different peer
  preferred: peer2,
  ignore, peer1
}

Environment details
Current setup:
1 org with 2 peers

Simple Endorsement policy:

```
{"identities":[{"role":{"name":"member","mspId":"Org1MSP"}}],policy:{"1-of":[{"signed-by":0}]}}
```

Fabric sdk libraries:

```
fabric-ca-client - v1.4.1
fabric-client - v1.4.1
fabric-network - v1.4.1
```

Hyperledger Fabric version: `v1.4.1`

Using the following approach to target specific peers in the sdk:

```
const request = {
      targets: peers or peer[1] or [peer2], -- target specific peer
      chaincodeId: chaincodeName,
      txId,
      fcn: functionName,
      args,
      transientMap: transientMapData // , // private data,
      ignore: list of peer[s] to ignore
      preferred: list of peer[s] to prefer
    };


    const endorsementResults = await channel.sendTransactionProposal(request);

    if (channel.verifyProposalResponse(endorsementResults[0][0])) {
      const transactionRequest = {
        proposalResponses: endorsementResults[0],
        proposal: endorsementResults[1]
      };
      invokeResponse = await channel.sendTransaction(transactionRequest);
    }
```

Expected results:

> transaction1 - client submits a transaction to peer1 and gets an endorsement back from peer1.
>   transaction2 - client submits a transaction to peer2 and gets an endorsement back from peer2.

Actual results:

> transaction1 - client submits a transaction to peer1 and gets an endorsement back from peer1.
>   transaction2 - client submits a transaction to peer2 and gets an endorsement back from peer1.